# Finding kth smallest number using quick sort

Tags: java, recursion

I am implementing an algorithm to find the Kth smallest element in an unsorted array using quick select. I am not sure where I am making a mistake. I am using the version of quick sort to find the kth smallest element. Rather than recursing through both partition , I am only recursing through one. Can anyone help me with this.

```
public class quickselect {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a={1,5,3,4,8,11};
        int ans=quick_select(a, 4, 0, a.length-1);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }


    private static int quick_select(int[] a, int k, int left, int right) {

        int pivot=findpivot(a,left,right);
        if(pivot==k-1){
            return a[pivot];
        }
        if(k-1<pivot){
            return quick_select(a, k, left, pivot-1);
        }
        else {
            return quick_select(a, k, pivot+1, right);
        }

    }

    private static int findpivot(int[] a, int left, int right) {

        int pivot = a[(left+right)/2];
        while(left<=right){
            while(a[left]<pivot){
                left++;
            }
            while(a[right]>pivot){
                right--;
            }

            if(left<=right){
                swap(a,left,right);
                left++;
                right--;
            }

        }
        return left;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {

        int temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;

    }

}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could give an explanation of where my mistake would be.

Comment: I wrote a blog post called "[Debugging Java code - A beginner's guide](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/)" which I think might help. Especially the part about debugging by printing. It's all you need for most standard algorithms. The short version is, be patient, follow the flow of the code.

Comment: @Keyser I was debugging it from a long time. Could not find the bug.I found the bug. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `findpivot` (which should be `findPivot` in CamelCase) :

```
while(left <= right)
```

should be

```
while(left < right)
```

Plus, you can write your `quick_select`method in a nicer fashion :

```
private static int quick_select(int[] a, int k, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = findpivot(a,left,right);
    return pivot == k - 1 ? a[pivot] : k - 1 < pivot ? 
            quick_select(a, k, left, pivot - 1) : 
            quick_select(a, k, pivot + 1, right);
}
```

Comment: Is your answer right? Don't you need to change the value of k in case your pivot is smaller than the k? because in the remaining set of elements, you won't be looking for kth smallest element now, instead you'll be looking for ```k - pivot``` smallest element?

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment when you posted it but I was at work and forgot about it. Just from looking at it and not running it, it looks ok to me. It's not going to be `k - pivot` as you put it because we always pass `a`, and not a sub-array of it. Therefore, `pivot` is always in `[0, a.length - 1]`, and the algorithm guarantees that an element which has been picked as the pivot in one iteration is at its correct index in the sorted array and won't move anymore. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just started to use the basic ```for(;;)``` loop with ```low >= high``` as the terminating condition inside, instead of recursive approach actually for this question, but yes that does make sense, thanks for finding the time after all these days, very nice of you!

Comment: No worries! Enjoy your programming :p